# Two column flex layout, align content towards the middle

Tags: html, css, flexbox

With this code:

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
}

.col {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class='row'>
  <div class='col'>
    <h1>Left</h1>
    <h2>Some longer text</h2>
  </div>
  <div class='col'>
    <h1>Right</h1>
    <h2>Some longer text</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

I get output like

```
------------------------------------------------------------------
|            Left               |             Right              |
|       Some longer text        |       Some longer text         |
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

(dashed lines imaginary to show containers).

What I want is for the elements in each column to stay centered relative to one another but to be biased towards the the column divider, with a bit of padding, e.g.

```
------------------------------------------------------------------
|                 Left        |       Right                      |
|           Some longer text  |  Some longer text                |
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Please find the attached [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mdsebans/745oz3wr/9/)

You can use align-items: center for vertical center alignment or and then for horizontal alignment, use align-self on particular element to flex-start, flex-end or center.

Just adding the css code here.

```
.row {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 -15px;
}

.col {
    flex: 1;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    padding: 0 15px;
}
.col:first-child h1,
.col:first-child h2{
align-self: flex-end;
}
.col:last-child h1,
.col:last-child h2{
align-self: flex-start;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I took a look at the fiddle. Left and Right (the h1 elements) are not centered with respect to the h2 elements below them, so it's not quite right...

Comment: Sorry about that, that was what I understood initially from your question. I have updated the fiddle now. Please have a look. Thanks
https://jsfiddle.net/mdsebans/745oz3wr/20/

Answer (score 0):

You could just `justify-content` as `center` in the row.

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.col {
  padding: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class='row'>
  <div class='col'>
    <h1>Left</h1>
    <h2>Some longer text</h2>
  </div>
  <div class='col'>
    <h1>Right</h1>
    <h2>Some longer text</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to put padding on the columns. Left padding on the left column and right padding on the right column. This example uses percentages. A limitation of this is when the text is longer it will wrap and not take up the full width of its container. You mention padding in your question, so it's possible you tried this.

#### Example

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}

.col {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
}

.col:nth-child(1) {
  padding-left: 20%;
}

.col:nth-child(2) {
  padding-right: 20%;
}


/*for example*/
.col {
  border: solid 1px #FEF;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class='row'>
  <div class='col'>
    <h1>Left</h1>
    <h2>Some longer text</h2>
  </div>
  <div class='col'>
    <h1>Right</h1>
    <h2>Some longer text</h2>
    <p>Really long text that might break break break break break break break break break break break break break break break break everything!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```